# Brownian motion: meaning of $B_t-B_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t-s)^{\bigotimes d}$

Tags: notation, brownian-motion

I am reading book "Brownian motion" from Schilling and Partzsch and I came across on notation that I am not sure did I understand it well. It is part of definition of $d$-dimensional Brownian motion
$$ B_t-B_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t-s)^{\bigotimes d}$$

Is meaning of this that $$B_t-B_s = (X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_d)$$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_d$ are independent and normal distibuted with expectation $0$ and variance $t-s$?

Comment: The first equation is notation that isn't too familiar with me, but you are correct in what it means, in that, you have explained what $d$-dim BM is thus the unfamiliar notation above must mean that otherwise if it means something else, it is incorrect.

Comment: Is it the ${}^{\otimes d}$ part you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, that part i don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do correctly understand what the notation refers to. It literally means that you have $d$ independent normal random variables as a $d$-tuple. I have never seen the notation $\mathcal N ^{\otimes d}$ before though. It seems strange to me. $X\sim \mathcal N$ just means that random variable $X$ follows the distribution indicated by $\mathcal N$ (normal distribution). The symbol $\otimes$ generally refers to some kind of product. It doesn't make sense to me to do $\mathcal N \otimes \mathcal N$ though. I think I can understand what is intended by it though.

In this particular context, we are working with random variables and stochastic processes. This is essentially part of measure theory. In measure theory there is a concept of *product measure*. So the particular probability measure on higher dimensional Brownian motion is related to the product measure on $d$ one-dimensional Brownian motions. The product of measures typically uses the $\otimes$ symbol. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure

Notice that $\times$ is used for the product of the spaces the variable takes values in, e.g. $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, but the sigma algebras use the $\otimes$ symbol. The symbol $\mathcal N$ does not represent a set or sigma algebra or a measure (it represents all three simultaneously in fact!), so using $\otimes$ on it feels strange to me. Maybe it is standard to do so though and I just haven't seen it yet.

One thought is that using $\otimes$ might imply the independence of the $d$ individual normal RVs. Higher dimensional Brownian motion isn't simply a bunch of normal random variables as those could have a variety of covariance relationships. Still though, applying it to $\mathcal N$ seems strange to me. As long as it is defined though, it would be fine.

E.g. I can take $(U,X)\sim \mathcal U(0,1) \otimes \text{Exp}(1)$ to mean that $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and $X$ is exponential with rate 1, and they are independent. Again, though, I have personally never seen $\otimes$ used in this way.